# Preventing Duplicate Entries - Ajax Not returning error. PHP MySQL jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm trying to prevent duplicate entires in my DB for a newsletter submissions form. I'm successfully preventing the duplicate entries, **but** I haven't been able to revise my the jQuery to print the error. I've included the PHP just incase I'm missing something there... Any help would be appreciated!

jQuery:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
        jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
            success: function() {
                $('#newsletterForm').html("<div id='success-message'></div>");
                $('#success-message').html("<p><strong>Thank you.</strong> <br/>You've been added to our list and will hear from us soon!</p>");
            },
            error: function() {
                $('#newsletterForm').html("<div id='success-message'></div>");
                $('#success-message').html("<p><strong>That email already exists.</strong> <br/>Please enter another email address.</p>");
            }
        });
    }
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {  
    $hasError = true;  
} else if (!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))) {  
    $hasError = true;  
} else {  
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);  
}  

if(!isset($hasError)) {  
    $con = mysql_connect("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx","user","pass");
        if (!$con)
            {
                die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
            }

    mysql_select_db("myDB", $con);

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(id) AS mycount FROM newsletter WHERE email = '$email'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if($row['mycount'] == 0) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO newsletter (email,dt) VALUES ('$email',NOW())";
        mysql_query($query) or die ("Error writing to database");
    } else {
         echo "I'm sorry our database already contains that email address. Please use a new email address to continue.";
    }

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
         {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
         }
    mysql_close($con);  
}  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error only gets called if your AJAX request fails (such as a 404).

Inside your `success: function() { }` you'll need to determine if what your PHP script returned was a success message, or error message. The easiest way to do this is with JSON instead of plain text.

To do this, in your PHP instead of echoing a string, do..

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>'success','response'=>'Everything worked');
```

or..

```
echo json_encode(array('result'=>'error','response'=>'Already exists');
```

Then in your ajax, set the dataType to 'json' and in your success function, you can then access the JSON as an object.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echoing out the messages, why can't you just print out a JSON representation of what happened? This will allow you to directly manipulate the object in JavaScript.

Remember: jQuery is not a language.